# Drag formula to every X rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to apply formula to every forth row in a column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Sheet1'!C$2:C$25;TRANSPOSE('Sheet2'!$E2:$AB2))
```

and point is that rows in range for 'Sheet2' have to add 1 row, like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Sheet1'!C$2:C$25;TRANSPOSE('Sheet2'!$E3:$AB3))
```

but system add 4 rows every time i drag or paste the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Sheet1'!C$2:C$25;TRANSPOSE('Sheet2'!$E6:$AB6))
=SUMPRODUCT('Sheet1'!C$2:C$25;TRANSPOSE('Sheet2'!$E10:$AB10))
```

pls help

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet file, that demonstrates the issue you're facing. This would allow the community to better replicate your actual problem & provide targeted solutions. If you're unsure, please refer to [Stack Overflow Guide on Creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: thx fo reply!
here is an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nnDO-08fqKCiwkG0dTLDL-ZEtxzCiMbfFbg7sEBNd6s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you interested in an *alternate approach* which doesn't require dragging down the formula?!

Comment: yes, I'm definitely interested! :)
my goal is to put formulas to cells and doesn't matter how, if it will work (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nnDO-08fqKCiwkG0dTLDL-ZEtxzCiMbfFbg7sEBNd6s/edit#gid=165711744) added to your sheet which you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(;1);B2:index(B:B;match(;0/(B:B<>"")));lambda(a;c;vstack(a;if(c="";tocol(;1);reduce(torow(;1);sequence(12);lambda(f;q;hstack(f;
 let(w;sumproduct(choosecols('materials / work'!C2:N49;q);tocol(filter(production!C:AX;production!B:B=c)));x;if(w=0;;w);y;offset(c;;2);z;y-x;Σ;iferror(z/y);Λ;iferror(z/x);
 vstack(x;z;Σ;Λ)))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: thx for your suggestion!
i got errors in every row "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in F4."
and it also replace formulas between F2-F6.
i tried it on "Sol" tab

Comment: **Do not drag the formula down**. the single formula in Cell_F2 gives out the whole output (*for all rows*).

Comment: works like magic!
many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

If you still want to utilize the formula dragging approach, skip certain rows, and keep the incremental ranges for the second range in your formula, you may also want to try using a custom script that will use the `onEdit` event to programmatically update the dragged formulas. Please see this sample script:

### Sample Script

```
/**
 * Custom Google Sheets script triggered on an edit event. 
 * This sample script is designed to be used in Google Sheets & is activated on any edit event.
 * 
 * It takes the currently selected range, retrieves the formulas, & then creates a modified version
 * of the data by removing every xRows-th row. The modified data is then pasted back into the sheet, starting from the
 * edited cell's row and column, with new, updated, and incremented ranges for the second range in the function (e.g., production!$C2:$AX2).
 *
 * @param {Object} e - The event object representing the edit event in Google Sheets.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const draggedRange = e.source.getSelection().getActiveRange();
  const draggedFormulas = draggedRange.getFormulas();
  const xRows = 4;
  const rowStart = e.range.rowStart;
  const column = e.range.getColumn();

  const finalData = draggedFormulas.map((row, i) =>
    row.map(x =>
      (i + 1) % xRows == 0 && i != 0 ? x : ''
    )
  );

  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(rowStart, column, finalData.length).setValues(finalData);
}
```

### Demo

> ***Note**: This method will remove existing cell data. Use it when creating a new copy of the sheet file.*

[image]

### Resources

[Add and create custom script to Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function)

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion!
unfortunately, it not working or maybe i did something wrong:
- after i added script to example file and put formula to cell, it completely delete formula from cell F2
- when i drag formula to rows below, it also erase formulas in cells F3:F5 and every time i fill anything to cells - it immediately erasing